# Constantly Hitting Deepcopy in Django with this Code - How to avoid?

Tags: django

I was expecting postgres to take some time, but wasn't expecting for it to not be the bottleneck here, how can i solve this?

```
2772856 function calls (2578490 primitive calls) in 32.361 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
127921/19340    3.670    0.000   11.486    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:145(deepcopy)
 2240    3.031    0.001    3.244    0.001 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2._psycopg.cursor' objects}
114402    1.541    0.000    2.348    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:267(_keep_alive)
```

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    suppliers = models.Supplier.objects.all().order_by('company')
    for supplier in suppliers :
        sup = {}
        sup['company'] = supplier.company
        sup['supplies'] = get_supplies(1, supplier.uuid)
        sup['category'] = 'Supplier'
        if isocode == None :
            addresses = models.Address.objects.filter(company = supplier.company)
        else :
            addresses = models.Address.objects.filter(company = supplier.company, country_iso = isocode)
        sup['contacts'] = models.Contact.objects.filter(address__in=addresses)
        company_list.append(sup)
```

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def get_supplies (bought_in_controlpanel_id, supplier_uuid) :

    supplier    = None
    activenode  = None

    if supplier_uuid is not None :
        supplier = models.Supplier.objects.get(uuid = supplier_uuid)

    try :
        activenode = boughtin.BoughtInControlPanel.objects.get (pk = 1)
    except :
        pass

    supplies = boughtin.BoughtInControlPanel.objects.filter (parent = activenode)
    for supply in supplies :
        supply.checked  = 0
        supply.disabled = ""
        supply.open     = 0

        if supplier_uuid is not None :
            try    :
                models.Supplies.objects.get(supplier = supplier, bought_in_control_panel = supply)
                supply.checked = 1
            except :
                supply.open    = 1

    return supplies
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is usually bad when you query DB in a loop. Try avoiding that.

Why not continue using relations and `__in` query? =)

I think this should work with less SQL queries for the first example:

```
company_list = models.Supplier.objects.values_list('company', flat=True)

filter_kwargs = dict(address__company__in=company_list)

if isocode is not None:
    filter_kwargs.update(dict(address__company__isocode=isocode))

sup['contacts'] = models.Contact.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

Regarding `get_supplies()`, I'd avoid `Supplies.objects.get()` in loop as well, unless you're sure it will be hit just a couple of times. It may be better to gather a list of supplies with one larger query before the loop, and then simply check if required item is present in that list. Although you should profile both variants and select the faster one.

Comment: isocode is supplied to the function `def company_list (area, sub_cat, isocode = None):` i have trimmed a lot of the function out as it's not relevent (alternate paths of this going to different models but doing exactly the same thing)

Comment: but basically all i do is `return company_list` at the end :)

Comment: Updated the answer with one possible way to account for `isocode` which I didn't think of initially.

Comment: Added a note about `get_supplies()`.

Comment: Thanks so much, you have managed to get me to drop from 32 seconds per request to just 4 :D

Comment: No problem. =) Still space for an improvement—in second example it appears you can use `supplies = boughtin.BoughtInControlPanel.objects.filter(parent__pk=1)`. Just keep in mind that with ORM it's still important to keep track of where you hit the DB, and use related lookups.